# What happens to existing tasks when queue.yaml is deployed?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, queue

If there is a queue with tasks, what happens when I deploy that same queue.yml?

Is there any risk of losing the queued tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the tasks will remain in the queue, even if you modify some of the elements of the task queue they belong to and redeploy the queue.yaml.